# Property deltaY doesn't exist on type event vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use mousewheel event for some purpose, the functionality works fine though it gives error "property deltaY does not exist on type event". For which I couldn't build my project. Any help will be appreciated

```
        H.addEvent(chart.container, 'mousewheel', function (event) {
          console.log('whwel',e);
            var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
            var extremes = xAxis.getExtremes();
            var step = 12 * 3600 * 1000;
            var newMin = extremes.min;
            var date = new Date(newMin);
              if (event.deltaY < 0) {
                date.getUTCDay() === 5 ? newMin += 3 * step : newMin += step;
              } else {
                date.getUTCDay() === 1 ? newMin -= 3 * step : newMin -= step;
              }
            xAxis.setExtremes(newMin, extremes.max, true);
        });
```

Comment: What is the code you are using? which  event are you listening to ?

Comment: I used mousewheel event. I tried using wheel event as well.I edited the question with some codes

Comment: First you need to use `wheel` event instead of `mousewheel`. Secondly, are you adding the event through a JS library? When you  add `console.log(event)` do you see `deltaY` property? or do you see `originalEvent` property.

Comment: now its working, when I updated my codes like this `H.addEvent(chart.container, 'wheel', function (event:WheelEvent)`. (event:WheelEvent) instead of only (event) as a argument made it worked